# Python of generating distinct binary tree

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new programmer in Python. Here is my code, and it gives me error. I really have no idea how to fix it.

Binary Tree class:

```
 class BinaryTree:
      def __init__(self, data):
          self.data=data
          self.right=None
          self.left=None
      def inOrderTraversal(self, root):
          if root == None:
             pass
          else:
             self.inOrderTraversal(root.left)
             print root.data,
             self.inOrderTraversal(root.right)
      def printOrder(self):
          self.inOrderTraversal(self)
```

Generate distinct all distinct trees

```
  def generateAllDistinctTrees(array,start,end):
      returnResultList=[]
      if start>end or start<0 or end>=len(array):
          return returnResultList.append(None)
      if start==end:
          treeNode = BinaryTree(array[start])
          return returnResultList.append(treeNode)
       for i in range(-1,end-start):
          leftResult = generateAllDistinctTrees(array,start+1,start+1+i)
          rightResult = generateAllDistinctTrees(array,start+2+i,end)
          for left in leftResult:
              for right in rightResult:
                  treeTemp = BinaryTree(array[start])
                  treeTemp.left = left
                  treeTemp.right = right
                  returnResultList.append(treeTemp)
  return returnResultList
```

I've also tried in this way by using appending

```
  def generateAllDistinctTrees(array,start,end):
      returnResultList=[]
      if start>end or start<0 or end>=len(array):
          return returnResultList.append(None)
      if start==end:
          treeNode = BinaryTree(array[start])
          return returnResultList.append(treeNode)
       for i in range(-1,end-start):
          leftResult=list()
          rightResult=list()
          leftResult.append(generateAllDistinctTrees(array,start+1,start+1+i))
          rightResult.append(generateAllDistinctTrees(array,start+2+i,end))
          for left in leftResult[0]:
              for right in rightResult[0]:
                  treeTemp = BinaryTree(array[start])
                  treeTemp.left = left
                  treeTemp.right = right
                  returnResultList.append(treeTemp)
  return returnResultList
```

Main function

```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
      preOrderData=[]
      scan = raw_input("Enter Number:")
      for i in range(0,int(scan)):
          preOrderData=preOrderData + [i+1]
      results = []
      results.append(generateAllDistinctTrees(preOrderData,0,len(preOrderData)-1))
      for eachObject in results[0]:
          eachObject.printOrder()
```

I've used the Java version of this code. And it works good without any error. But in python, it will give me following errors:

For the first version if generateAllDistinctTrees:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 10, in generateAllDistinctTrees
      File "<stdin>", line 11, in generateAllDistinctTrees
  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

For the second version of generateAllDistinctTrees: (using appending one)

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
      File "<stdin>", line 9, in generateAllDistinctTrees
  NameError: global name 'leftResult' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance!!!

I attached my screen shot here!!

[image]

Comment: ```NameError: global name 'leftResult' is not defined``` means that you are trying to *use* ```leftResult``` before anything has been assigned to it in generateAllDistinctTrees(). generateAllDistinctTrees() cannot *see* leftResult.  It must not be in that function's local or global scope.  Maybe add ```leftResult = list()``` and ```rightResult = list()``` at the top of the function.    [Python Scopes and Namespaces](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).  [Naming and binding](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

Comment: @wwii so you mean the second way of using generatingAllDistinctTrees is the correct way. I mean using append is the correct way?

Comment: @wwii after adding that, it start to give me the same error as first version of generateAllDistinctTrees which is NoneType object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

```
class BinaryTree:
      left, right, data = None, None, 0
```

This is wrong. It will create variables that belong to the class, not to the instances (meaning that there won't be several copies for several trees).
The correct way is to just assign variables in the constructor, using self.variable = value.

I see an indentation problem where a "pass" is at the same level as a "def" that should contain it. In general your indentation is not very consistent, you should always use 4 spaces, the returns should be inside the functions.

Fix those easy mistakes so it's easier to look at the logical ones.

Comment: you mean adding self.left = None and self.right = None in _init_ ? Thanks.

Comment: also, but also the indentation needs to be fixed... I didn't look at the logic

Comment: It still gives me the same error. Should I use the first version of generateAllDistinctTrees or second version with appending thing...